# jQuery custom tabs not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I am having a little trouble working out why my tabs content is not switching correctly, only seems to work on the last one. Does anyone have any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/x04o2kb6/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    var activateTab = function(index) {
        var tab = $(".tabs-menu li:eq(" + index + ")"),
            tabContent = $(".tab div:eq(" + index + ")");

        tab.addClass("active");
        tab.siblings().removeClass("active");
        tabContent.siblings().css("display", "none");
        tabContent.show();
    }

    var automation = {
        start: function() {
            this.current = setInterval(function() {
                var currentIndex = $(".tabs-menu li.active").index(),
                    max = $(".tabs-menu li.active").parent().children().length;
                activateTab(currentIndex + 1 < max ? currentIndex + 1 : 0);
            }, 2000);
        },
        stop: function() {
            if (this.current) {
                clearInterval(this.current);
            }
        }
    }

    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        activateTab($(event.currentTarget).parent().index());
    });

    //automation.start();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your activateTab function as following -

```
var activateTab = function(index) {
    var tab = $(".tabs-menu li:eq(" + index + ")"),
        tabContent = $(".tab > div:eq(" + index + ")");

    tab.addClass("active");
    tab.siblings().removeClass("active");
    tabContent.siblings().css("display", "none");
    tabContent.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong css selector, when you are selecting tab content divs. Use this one to select only the childs `tabContent = $(".tab > div:eq(" + index + ")");`
Your css selector seleted all divs.

Answer (score 0):

You weren't referring proper `tabContent`. It always used to fetch `index` i.e. whatever you pass to function, say could be 3, 2, and that particular `div` was fetched irrespective of its hierarchy.. Just change with exact class:

```
tabContent = $(".tab div.mainFeatureCopy:eq(" + index + ")");
```

refer `div` with its class here i.e. `mainFeatureCopy`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/x04o2kb6/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please check now I have updated  `tabContent = $(".tab>div:eq(" + index + ")");` Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x04o2kb6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
tabContent = $(".tab div:eq(" + index + ")")
```

don't get the right object, you should use

```
tabContent = $(".tab-content:eq(" + index + ")")
```